# Flagging a post that's already been flagged

Tags: discussion

Is it bad form to flag a post that's already been flagged? Does doing this create more work?

For example, I just came across [this posted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73076/use-synaptic-package-installer-by-default/296996#296996), which doesn't attempt to address the question. There's a comment suggesting to ask a new question and a link saying it came from the low-quality post review queue.

I went ahead and flagged it, which I've done a few times in similar situations. Should I avoid doing so in the future?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it shouldn't cause extra work (can't be in the queue more than once), and even if it did, that'd be a bug in the site which should be fixed. The workload on Unix.SE is not overwhelming.

It was actually still in the review queue until just now, when I gave it a delete vote, deleting it.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/150874